# Is it possible for Pandoc to detect cross-references when converting from Word?

Tags: ms-word, markdown, pandoc

I have a minimal Word (.docx) document that contains a figure and cross-reference to it (see image below; Figure 1: Some figure). When I Ctrl+click on that cross-reference, it puts me back on the image.

But when I convert this document to markdown or native format using `pandoc -s file.docx -t markdown -o file.md` or `pandoc -s file.docx -t native -o file.txt`, the cross-reference is parsed as regular text.

What I am wondering is if it is possible for Pandoc to detect and parse such instances in .docx document using some filter or some other method. Note that cross-references to tables, chapters, and subchapters are also relevant for me.

[image]

Comment: There's a relevant issue on the pandoc repository: [*docx reader: Internal references and SEQ numbers do not work*](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/2791).

Comment: I did not find that site, sorry for that. If you want, you can write answer, which I will accept.